# Why do i get nan when i run this program?

Tags: objective-c, nan, xcode4.6

I have a program here that solves the mathematical equation : (3.31 * 10 to the -8 power + 2.01 * 10 to the -7 power)/(7.16 * 10 to the -6 power + 2.01 * 10 to the -8 power)...However,my out put always results in nan! Please tell me why and help me fix it.

```
int a = 10;
    int b = -10;
    //10 to the -8 power below
    float ab = 1 / (a * b * b * b * b * b * b * b) ;
    //10 to the -7 power below
    float ba = 1 / (a * b * b * b * b * b * b) ;
    //10 to the -6 power below
    float abc = 1 / (a * b * b * b * b * b) ;
    //equation below
    double conclusion = (3.31 * ab + 2.01 * ba) / (7.16 * abc + 2.01 * ab);
    NSLog(@"the answer to the equation is %f",conclusion);
```

Comment: `double conclusion = (3.31E-8 + 2.01E-7) / (7.16E-6 + 2.01E-8);`

Answer (score 1):

Your expressions are calculated as integers.  In integers, 1/100 evaluates to 0.

Just change your a and b declarations to this:

```
float a = 10;
float b = -10;
```

Then all the calculations will be floats and will have the values you expect.

Also, this is calculating the numbers in a rather strange way.  You might as well just enter them as floating point literals like `3.31E-8`, which is 3.31 * 10 to the -8 power.

Comment: Or leave a and b as int but change the 1 to 1.0. But replacing this whole mess with a few simple float literals is by far the better idea.